# jQuery uncheck all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following jQuery script correctly displaying and checking two hidden checkboxes.  The only problem is that I'm trying to hide both of these checkboxes but when I uncheck my visible checkbox they remain checked?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="JobType[]" class="visiChk" id="nineteen" value="19" <?php echo (isset($_GET["JobType"]) && !empty($_GET["JobType"]) && in_array("19", $_GET["JobType"])) ? "checked": ""; ?> /> Plumbing
<label id="hiddenLabel" style="display:none">
<input type="checkbox" name="JobType[]" class="visiChk" id="seventeen" value="17" <?php echo (isset($_GET["JobType"]) && !empty($_GET["JobType"]) && in_array("17", $_GET["JobType"])) ? "checked": ""; ?> /> Plumbing
<input type="checkbox" name="JobType[]" class="visiChk" id="eighteen" value="18" <?php echo (isset($_GET["JobType"]) && !empty($_GET["JobType"]) && in_array("18", $_GET["JobType"])) ? "checked": ""; ?> /> Plumbing
</label>
    <script>
    // update if any are checked/unchecked
$('.visiChk').change(function() {
    var hiddenLabel = $('#hiddenLabel')[0];
    var seventeen = $('#seventeen')[0];
    var eighteen = $('#eighteen')[0];

    // Are any of them checked ?
    if ($('.visiChk:checked').length > 0) {
        hiddenLabel.style.display = 'block';
        seventeen.checked = true;
        eighteen.checked = true;
    } else  {
        hiddenLabel.style.display = 'none';
        seventeen.checked = false;
        eighteen.checked = false;
    }
});</script>
```

Comment: Your title says you want to uncheck them, your question says you want to hide them. Which is it?

Comment: You're setting `hiddenLabel.style.display = 'block'` in both the `if` and `else`. Shouldn't the second one be `none`? Why aren't you using jQuery `hide()` and `show()`?

Comment: Typo, it's fixed.  Question remains.  Why did I eat tacos last night?  B/C I chose too...same reason why I chose this method.

Comment: Your last edit to the question fixed the problem that you describe in the question. Please don't do that, it makes my answer meaningless.

Comment: Your answer didn't fix the problem...it was a typo that had no affect on the actual problem.

Comment: Then your question doesn't describe the problem well. It says "I'm trying to hide both of these checkboxes", and my answer directly addressed that. If there's some other problem, like the checkboxes not getting unchecked, you need to say that in the question.

Comment: Good point, I appended the text to say the checkboxes remain unchecked.

Comment: Are you saying you want to set it so that if one is checked and if one is unchecked, they are all unchecked and when they are all checked then hide the two in the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a logical error occurring here that might not be readily obvious with the hidden fields. When you are checking to see if any of the checkboxes are marked, you're checking **all** of them, even the hidden ones.

So, walk through the cycle once more. The page loads, no checkboxes have been checked. A user checks the visible one. All three are checked. The user then unchecks only the visible one. Your logic check here

```
if ($('.visiChk:checked').length > 0) {
```

is looking at all three of them. Are there any checked? Yes, the two hidden ones still are! So, all three will be set to checked again. You'll need a way to only look at the visible checkbox and then update the invisible ones accordingly. A unique ID or different class would work well.

I wrote up an example jsfiddle that helps to illustrate what's going on. Instead of hiding the checkboxes, I set the font color to grey to show which ones should actually be hidden.

https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/d9geaog4/1/

Edit: Also, I set up a console log to show the result of the logic check going on. When the page first loads (no checkboxes are checked) and the user checks one, it evaluates to 1. Uncheck the visible one, and it evaluates to 2 - showing the 2 hidden checkboxes are still being counted.

Edit 2: Here's the code from the jsfiddle for reference in case the fiddle is ever lost.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="JobType[]" id="nineteen" class="visiChk" value="19"  /> Plumbing
<label id="hiddenLabel" style="color:silver; /*display:none*/">
    <input type="checkbox" name="JobType[]" class="visiChk" id="seventeen" value="17" /> Plumbing
    <input type="checkbox" name="JobType[]" class="visiChk" id="eighteen" value="18" /> Plumbing
</label>
```

JS

```
// update if any are checked/unchecked
$('.visiChk').change(function() {
    var hiddenLabel = $('#hiddenLabel')[0];
    var seventeen = $('#seventeen')[0];
    var eighteen = $('#eighteen')[0];

    // Are any of them checked ?
    console.log($('#nineteen:checked').length);

    if ($('#nineteen:checked').length > 0) {
        hiddenLabel.style.display = 'block';
        seventeen.checked = true;
        eighteen.checked = true;
    } else {
        // Commenting this out so the hidden fields stay visible for demo purposes
        //hiddenLabel.style.display = 'none'; 
        seventeen.checked = false;
        eighteen.checked = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: So by making my visible id="nineteen" now how do I achieve the proper results?

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco `if ($"#nineteen").is(":checked"))`

Comment: if( $('#nineteen:checked').length > 0 ) or you can also Barmar's method. Both should work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand?  Can you update the jsfiddle to show how I'd make sure to uncheck the two grey checkboxes when the original checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: Thanks so much, this is awesome @sm1215